# find an asymptotic expansion by using the Watson's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics

I want to apply the Watson's theorem to find an asymptotic expansion for the function $$f(z)=\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{-z \frac{y^{2}}{2}} \sin(y^{2})dy$$
(Assume $z \rightarrow \infty, z>0$). But I need to find a domain which contains the real axis and the function:

$$g(z)=\sin(z^{2})$$

Is bounded on it? Is there any such domain? If $z=x+iy$ then: 
$$|g(z)| \leq \frac{e^{-2xy}+e^{2xy}}{2}$$ 
But the right hand side is not bounded for any domain $|y|<c, c>0$.

Comment: Why do you need to find such a domain?  This can be done without referencing the complex plane at all.  Applying Watson's lemma is straightforward here; just break apart the integral like $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} = \int_{-\infty}^0 + \int_0^\infty$ and apply Watson's lemma to each piece.

Comment: But we have that hypothesis in the theorem!

Comment: I see, I thought you were referring to [this Watson's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma), which doesn't need any such condition.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$
f(z)=\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{-z \frac{y^{2}}{2}} \sin(y^{2})\mathrm dy=2\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-z \frac{y^{2}}{2}} \sin(y^{2})\mathrm dy
$$
and putting $t=\frac{y^2}{2}$ we have
$$
f(z)=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-z t} 2\frac{\sin (2t)}{\sqrt{2t}}\mathrm dt.
$$
Observe that, 
$$
g(t)=2\frac{\sin (2t)}{\sqrt{2t}}
$$
is continuous in $(0,\infty)$, and using the Taylor's series for $\sin(2t)$,
$$
g(t)=2\frac{\sin (2t)}{\sqrt{2t}}\sim \frac{2}{\sqrt{2t}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k (2t)^{2 k+1}}{(2 k+1)!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \underbrace{\frac{(-1)^k 2^{2 k+\frac{3}{2}}}{(2 k+1)!}}_{a_k}t^{\overbrace{2 k+\frac{3}{2}}^{\lambda_k}-1}.
$$
that is $g(t)\sim \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k t^{{\lambda_k}-1}$ for $t\to 0$ with $0<\lambda_0<\lambda_1<\ldots$.

Moreover, for some fixed $c>0$, $g(t)=\mathcal{O}(e^{ct})$ for $t\to\infty$.

Thus, for the Watson's Lemma,
$$
f(z)\sim \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k \frac{\Gamma(\lambda_k)}{z^{\lambda_k}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k 2^{2 k+\frac{3}{2}}}{(2 k+1)!}\frac{\Gamma\left(2 k+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{z^{2 k+\frac{3}{2}}}
$$
for $|z|\to\infty$ and $|\mathrm{arg}(z)|<\frac{\pi}{2}-\delta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ for some $\delta$ such that $0<\delta<\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: I got the solution, thank you very much. But I still wonder whether we have the domain or not, do you have any idea about that?

Comment: I don't understand your question...The Watson's Lemma states some conditions on $g(t)$ and then gives an asymptotic expansion for $f(z)$ as $z\to\infty$. What is your formulation of the Lemma?

Comment: I am studying the book 'Basic Complex Analysis' by Marsden and there is no Watson's lemma but Watson's theorem (page 436), have you seen that?

Comment: @user135582, instead of "Watson's theorem", use Proposition 7.2.5 with alexjo's argument.

Comment: The Theorem in Marsden is the Watson's Lemma in a less common formulation.
In the theorem you have $z$ real! So in your case, $0\le |\sin(z^2)|\le 1$.

Thus
$$
g(y)=\sin (y^2)\sim y^2-\frac{y^6}{3!}+\cdots
$$
and 
$$
f(z)\sim \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\sqrt z}\left(a_0+\frac{a_2}{z}+\frac{a_4\cdot 1 \cdot 3}{z^2}+\frac{a_6\cdot 1 \cdot 3\cdot 5}{z^3}+\cdots\right)
$$
where $a_0=0, \, a_2=1,\, a_4=0,\, a_6=-\frac{1}{3!}$; thus
$$
f(z)\sim \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\sqrt z}\left(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{3!}\frac{1 \cdot 3\cdot 5}{z^3}+\cdots\right)
$$
as $z\to \infty,\,\mathrm{arg}(z)=0$.

Comment: I had the same approximation when I assumed that I had all hypothesis but I think the $z$ in $f(z)$ is real and still we have the condition that the function g is analytic and bounded on a domain which contains the real axis! Thanks.